# Java- Striking through item in ListView javafx?

Tags: listview, javafx, strikethrough

I want to strikethrough text in my listview. I tried the following codes but it's not working. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
.list-cell {
   -fx-text-fill: red;
   -fx-strikethrough: true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListCell` does not have the strikethrough property.  You probably want to apply the CSS to the text element inside the cell, roughly:

```
.list-cell .text {
    -fx-strikethrough: true;
}
```

See also the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Comment: OMGGG! Thank You :)